# How can we make a pie chart using dygraph

Tags: pie-chart, dygraphs

I would like to create pie chart using dygraph library. On the main site http://dygraphs.com/, i could't find the way to create pie chart

Answer (score 2):

dygraphs is a library for creating line charts. You can't use it to create pie charts. There are many other JavaScript visualization libraries out there that will meet your needs better, for example the Google Visualization API or HighCharts.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create pie charts using dygraphs using plotter plugin.

See the below link for the same-

> https://varolokan.wordpress.com/2017/04/24/dygraphs-pie-chart-plotter/